# R - conditionally substracting entire row values from different dataframe

Tags: r

I have two dataframes, df 1 is as follows (example):

```
individuals  species  element1  element2  element3

POR20_02       dia     0.003     0.005     0.001

POR20-03       het     0.005     0.009     0.002

POR20-04       hyb     0.002     0.007     0.005
```

**Note** : this dataframe has 1080 columns and 15 rows.

`df2` is as follows

```
species   element1   element2  element3

dia        0.004       0.006     0.002

hyb        0.007       0.006     0.003

het        0.004       0.005     0.006
```

**Note** : this dataframe has 1.079 columns (since there is no individuals columns) and 3 rows.

I would like to substract the values from an entire row in `df1` by an entire row of `df2` when the species are the same.

i.e.

POR20-02 is a dia so I would like to substract its element1 by the dia element1 in `df2` (then the same for each elements)

**Note** : the values of df2 are the element averages per species 0f df1.

What I'm trying to do is find the difference between the value of each element of each individuals and the value of the species average.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <-
  tibble(
    individuals  = "POR20_02",
    species = "dia",
    element1 = .003,
    element2 = .005,
    element3 = .001
  )

df2 <-
  tibble(
    species = "dia",
    element1 = .001,
    element2 = .006,
    element3 = .005
  )

 df1  %>% 
  left_join(df2,by = "species",suffix = c("_df","_df2")) %>% 
  mutate(
    across(
      .cols = ends_with("_df"),
      .fns = ~ . - (get(paste0(cur_column(),"2"))),
      .names = "diff_{.col}"
    )
  ) %>% 
  glimpse()

Rows: 1
Columns: 11
$ individuals      <chr> "POR20_02"
$ species          <chr> "dia"
$ element1_df      <dbl> 0,003
$ element2_df      <dbl> 0,005
$ element3_df      <dbl> 0,001
$ element1_df2     <dbl> 0,001
$ element2_df2     <dbl> 0,006
$ element3_df2     <dbl> 0,005
$ diff_element1_df <dbl> 0,002
$ diff_element2_df <dbl> -0,001
$ diff_element3_df <dbl> -0,004
```